# Why is ROS Publisher not publishing values?

Tags: python, ros

I am currently trying to write a Python ROS program which can be executed as a ROS node (using rosrun) that implements the defs declared in a separate Python file arm.py (available at: https://github.com/nortega1/dvrk-ros/...). The program initially examines the current cartesian position of the arm. Subsequently, when provided with a series of points that the arm must pass through, the program calculates a polynomial equation and given a range of x values the program evaluates the equation to find the corresponding y values.

Within the `arm.py` file there is a publisher `set_position_cartesian_pub` that sets the Cartesian position of the arm as follows:

```
self.__set_position_cartesian_pub = rospy.Publisher(self.__full_ros_namespace + '/set_position_cartesian', Pose, latch = True, queue_size = 1)
```

The issue is that the publisher set_position_cartesian is not publishing the values of the newPose to the robot - can anyone figure out what the issue might be? I can confirm that the def lagrange correctly calculates the values of the x and y coordinates, which are printed out to the terminal via the command rospy.loginfo(newPose). Any help would be greatly appreciated as I've been trying to solve this issue for the last 2 days!

```
#! /usr/bin/python
import rospy
import sys
from std_msgs.msg import String, Bool, Float32
from geometry_msgs.msg import Pose
from geometry_msgs.msg import PoseStamped
from geometry_msgs.msg import Vector3
from geometry_msgs.msg import Quaternion
from geometry_msgs.msg import Wrench

class example_application:

def callback(self, data):
  self.position_cartesian_current = data.pose
  rospy.loginfo(data.pose)

def configure(self,robot_name):
    self._robot_name = 'PSM1'
    ros_namespace = '/dvrk/PSM1'
    rospy.Subscriber('/dvrk/PSM1/position_cartesian_current', PoseStamped, self.callback)
    self.set_position_cartesian = rospy.Publisher('/dvrk/PSM1/set_position_cartesian', Pose, latch=True, queue_size = 10)
    rospy.sleep(3)
    rospy.init_node('listener', anonymous=True)
    rospy.spin()

def lagrange(self, f, x):
 total = 0
 n = len(f)
 for i in range(n):
  xi, yi = f[i]
  def g(i, n):
   g_tot = 1
   for j in range(n):
    if i == j:
     continue
    xj, yj = f[j]
    g_tot *= (x - xj) / float(xi - xj)

   return g_tot

  total += yi * g(i, n)
 return total

def trajectoryMover(self):
    newPose = Pose()
    points =[(0.0156561,0.123151),(0.00715134,0.0035123151),(0.001515177,0.002123151),(0.0071239751,0.09123150)]
    xlist = [i*0.001 for i in range(10)]
    ylist = [self.lagrange(points, xlist[i])*0.001 for i in range(10)]
    for x, y in zip(xlist, ylist):
        newPose.position.x = x
        newPose.position.y = y
        newPose.position.z = 0.001
        newPose.orientation.x = 0.001
        newPose.orientation.y = 0.001
        newPose.orientation.z = 0.005
        newPose.orientation.w = 0.002
        rospy.sleep(1)
        self.set_position_cartesian.publish(newPose)
        rospy.loginfo(newPose)
        rospy.spin()

def run(self):
    # self.home()
    self.trajectoryMover()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        if (len(sys.argv) != 2):
            print(sys.argv[0] + ' requires one argument, i.e. name of dVRK arm')
    else:
        application = example_application()
        application.configure(sys.argv[1])
        application.run()

except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
    pass
```

Comment: Is it not publishing it, or is the robot not receiving it? Are your sure the issue is with the publisher, not the subscriber? Have you checked with rostopic whether something is published?

Comment: After running the script and subsequently running the command `rostopic echo /dvrk/PSM1/set_postion_cartesian` the following message is displayed: 
**WARNING: topic [/dvrk/PSM1/set_postion_cartesian] does not appear to be published yet** which suggests that the publisher is not correct? However after looking at the ROS tutorials, I can't figure out why

Answer (score 2):

You are not publishing because the code stops at `rospy.spin()` when you call `application.configure()`. For what I understand of what you are trying to do, the code will publish 10 poses to a topic, then you don't need it anymore.

I've moved the location of `rospy.spin()`, but the code needs more revision than that.

```
#! /usr/bin/python
import rospy
import sys
from std_msgs.msg import String, Bool, Float32
from geometry_msgs.msg import Pose
from geometry_msgs.msg import PoseStamped
from geometry_msgs.msg import Vector3
from geometry_msgs.msg import Quaternion
from geometry_msgs.msg import Wrench

class example_application(object):
    def callback(self, data):
        self.position_cartesian_current = data.pose
        rospy.loginfo(data.pose)

    def configure(self,robot_name):
        self._robot_name = 'PSM1'
        ros_namespace = '/dvrk/PSM1'
        rospy.Subscriber('/dvrk/PSM1/position_cartesian_current', PoseStamped, self.callback)
        self.set_position_cartesian = rospy.Publisher('/dvrk/PSM1/set_position_cartesian', Pose, latch=True, queue_size = 10)

    def lagrange(self, f, x):
        total = 0
        n = len(f)
        for i in range(n):
            xi, yi = f[i]
            def g(i, n):
                g_tot = 1
                for j in range(n):
                    if i == j:
                        continue
                    xj, yj = f[j]
                    g_tot *= (x - xj) / float(xi - xj)

                return g_tot

            total += yi * g(i, n)
        return total

    def trajectoryMover(self):
        newPose = Pose()
        points =[(0.0156561,0.123151),(0.00715134,0.0035123151),(0.001515177,0.002123151),(0.0071239751,0.09123150)]
        xlist = [i*0.001 for i in range(10)]
        ylist = [self.lagrange(points, xlist[i])*0.001 for i in range(10)]
        for x, y in zip(xlist, ylist):
            newPose.position.x = x
            newPose.position.y = y
            newPose.position.z = 0.001
            newPose.orientation.x = 0.001
            newPose.orientation.y = 0.001
            newPose.orientation.z = 0.005
            newPose.orientation.w = 0.002
            self.set_position_cartesian.publish(newPose)
            rospy.loginfo(newPose)

    def run(self):
        # self.home()
        self.trajectoryMover()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if (len(sys.argv) != 2):
        print(sys.argv[0] + ' requires one argument, i.e. name of dVRK arm')
    else:
        application = example_application()
        application.configure(sys.argv[1])
        application.run()

    try:
        rospy.spin()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        rospy.loginfo("Keyboard Interrupt")
```

Think of:

- making the script argument a parameter of the node.
- moving the `configure` method to the `__init__` method.
- taking the `g()` function outside `lagrange()`.

It's a good practice to use relative topic names, instead of absolute ones (absolute: topic name start with `/`, e.g.: `'/dvrk/PSM1'`).